# Vuejs Cannot destructure property

Tags: node.js, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I have an auth.js with a function signUp():

```
  async signUp(_, { username, password, firstName, lastName }) {
    const data = await Auth.signUp({
      username,
      password,
      attributes: {
        given_name: firstName,
        family_name: lastName,
      },
    });
    console.log(data);
  },
};
```

In Registration.vue methods:, I'm trying to pass username and password like this:

```
   async submitReg() {
      AWSAuth.actions.signUp({
          username: this.form.email,
          password: this.form.password
        });
```

However, I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property
> 'username' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
> at Object.signUp (auth.js?0a5a:103)
> at VueComponent.submitReg (VM20046 Register.vue:32)

Why? I don't understand why username is undefined when "this.form.email" has a value "string.

Comment: normal js for now, just installed Vuex and intend to use that once I work it out :)

Comment: Ok then remove `_` as first param. that's it!!

Comment: that works, but what will _ be used for in Vuex?

Comment: Actually that is [context](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#:~:text=Action%20handlers%20receive%20a%20context%20object) object in `actions`, which holds some predefined methods, like `commit and dispatch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're destructing the second parameter which is undefined, remove the `_` which is defined as first parameter:

```
async signUp({ username, password, firstName, lastName }) {
```

if `signUp` is an action it should be called via dispatch method :

```
this.$store.dispatch("signUp",{
          username: this.form.email,
          password: this.form.password
        })
```

then the first param will the context callback and the second is your payload :

```
async signUp({commit}, { username, password, firstName, lastName }) {

...
```